# How to modify a string in an array to contain special characters using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a pretty straight forward question on how to alter a string within an array using javascript.

I'm having trouble getting it to input some special characters using .replace

```
function myFunction(text) {

var colArray = $('#tblSearch td:nth-child(1)').map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
        }).get();

for(var i=0; i < colArray.length; i++) {
 colArray[i] = colArray[i].replace(/Roogle | Remedy/g, '');
 colArray[i] = colArray[i].replace(/[|]/g, '');
                                        }
}
```

Using this, I'm able to turn a string like this:

INC00001111111 Johnny | Appleseed

Into this:

INC00001111111

However, I'd like to turn the above into this (double quotes ARE part of the string):

"'Incident ID*+'="INC00001111111" OR

Any ideas on how to do this? The special characters are killing me.

Comment: if you have INC00001111111 inside a variable, just concatenate strings before and after. Use a backslash \ to escape " or ' in your string.

Answer (score 0):

> INC00001111111
>     However, I'd like to turn the above into this (double quotes ARE part of the string)

I don't know what you are trying to do, but to add quotes to a string you can do this:

```
var str = "\"INC00001111111\"";
//or
var str1 = '"' + "INC00001111111" + '"';
```

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "INC00001111111"; 
var b = "\"'Incident ID*+'=\""+a+"\" OR";
```

a was the string INC00001111111, b is now the string "'Incident ID*+'="INC00001111111" OR